# Unfamiliar use of square brackets during multiple variable declaration in Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, syntax

I'm a beginner to Javascript and encountered this syntax usage(simplified):

```
var testString ="firstName, lastName";
var [a,b] = testString.split(", ");
```

My question is what typeof variable a & b then becomes at line2?
*My simplistic investigation seems to indicate a & b are assigned respective string values.*

**But what goes on under the hood?** why do we use square brackets [] here? Isn't an array returned & created in the process by .split()? Otherwise, what objects were created in the background?
Links to understand this style of declaration for [a,b] would also be welcomed.

Comment: It's a [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), an ES6 feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> But what goes on under the hood?

```
// You declare a string variable
var testString = "firstName, lastName";

// Split method help you to divide the string value according with the
//indicated separator, in this examle the comma
var [a,b] = testString.split(", ");
```

> The destructuring assignment syntax is a JavaScript expression that
>   makes it possible to unpack values from arrays, or properties from
>   objects, into distinct variables.

Since the **split** function returns an array, with the `var [a,b] = array`
you are assigning the value in index order, in the example:

```
console.log(a); // 'firstName'
console.log(b); // 'lastName'
```

And they are simple string variables. You may want to vist the links below:

[Destructuring asignation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)

[split function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Further resources: Since you have mentioned you are beginning with JS, I suggest you to read books mentioned in this magnific [post](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/12-books-every-javascript-developer-should-read-9da76157fb3)

Comment: Thanks for the informative breakdown and links. Interesting that no eventual array was created in the process but only a & b as string primitives.

Comment: Yes it is, also you can use the rest operator `var [a, b, ...c] = [1, 2, 3, 4];` what value do you think is going to hold the variable `c`?

Comment: `c` contains an array (The rest values that were not assigned "individually")

Comment: Thanks Ricardo, I learnt something new about the **... rest operator** too. I've actually been starting to read the You don't know Js by Kyle Simpson, but some parts are abit hard to comprehend at once, so I'll probably have to do more exercises and re-read the chapters again.

Answer (score 1):

This is [destructuring assignment.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) It resembles the pattern-matching found in many functional languages.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt help, looks like quite a bit to wrap my head around.